# reshuffle array value in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am adding other value array inside foreach loop which working fine for me.

```
$i = true;
$array = array('red', 'blue');
foreach($array as $key => & $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
    if ($i === true) {
         $others = array('white', 'yellow');
         foreach($others as $key => & $other_value) {
             $array[] = $other_value;    
         }
    }
    $i = false;
}
```

Output

```
red
blue
white
yellow
```

but i want to reshuffle array value inside foreach loop need output like below

```
red
white
yellow
blue
```

Comment: what do you mean by reshuffle?

Comment: You iterate over your array from beginning to end. Doing any kind of `reshufling` during this iteration seems useless to me and may lead to unforseen behaviour of a loop.

Comment: BTW, adding new array to array can be done with `array_merge` in one line of code.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII which array me added in foreach that should come first

Comment: Is there any structure in your sorting? Like alphabetical, etc. ? You could apply a custom sorting function with usort.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting that output. Your code only echoes the values from `$array`, not `$others`, how are the values from `$others` getting into the output?

Comment: @Barmar see output http://ideone.com/9pYCgV

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it on `$array` without some serious `array_slice()`ing.  So, just assign to another array `$result` and you will get the `$other` array inserted between the first and second elements of `$array`:

```
$i = true;
$array = array('red', 'blue');
foreach($array as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;  // here...
    if ($i === true) {
         $others = array('white', 'yellow');
         foreach($others as $other_value) {
             $result[] = $other_value;  // and here...
         }

    }
    $i = false;
}
```

If needed (for whatever reason) `$array = $result;`

Answer (score 1):

A cool solution would be like this:

```
$array = array('red', 'blue');
$others = array('white', 'yellow');

$temp = array_combine($array,$others);

$final = array();

foreach($temp as $key => $value) {
    array_push($final,$key,$value);
}

$array = $final;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = true;
$array = array('red', 'blue');
foreach($array as $key => & $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
    if ($i === true) {
          $a1= $array;
          $a2= array($value);
          $result=array_diff($a1,$a2);

          $others = array('white', 'yellow');
          $array =  array_merge($others,$result);
    }
    $i = false;
}
```

[see output](http://ideone.com/DPrRfN)